# Starting GlassFish 4 Error after installing a second version of jdk

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

I have installed a **Glassfish 4 Server** in **Eclipse Neon** in which I have deployed a web project.

As part of a project I have recently installed Glassfish 3.1.2.2 (which is compatible with java S.E 6 or 7). So I have two versions of jdk installed in two different folders.

But when I want to start the Glassfish 4 I get the following error:

[image]

I have edited the `asenv.conf` and set the value of `AS_JAVA` but I am still getting this error. Can I have some solutions please ?

Comment: It looks like you have configured Glassfish 4 incorrectly.

Comment: Finally It works. I just had to specify the right path to in Eclipse preferences.